# Emacs as IDE: Handling a project directory?

Tags: visual-studio, emacs, file-structure

I've always used emacs for small projects (and Visual Studio for large ones). I was wondering what the alternatives are for handling a directory structure within emacs, something like the solution explorer in VS. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should also have a look at [eproject](http://github.com/jrockway/eproject/tree/master) for something that's more lightweight while also allowing you do to some pretty cool stuff (like project-specific config settings, etc.)

Comment: I second the eproject recommendation.  It has made my life measurably better ;)

Comment: what exactly does eproject do?  I looked at the wiki and the home page had a link for how to install it, but not WHY I would want to install it.  What does it do? Examples?   @jrockway - you're the guy that wrote it, no?

Comment: I think the OP was looking for something to handle VS .sln files.  Does eproject do that?

Comment: @Cheeso -- have a look at http://wiki.github.com/jrockway/eproject/eprojectexamples

Answer (score 8):

[ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/), the Emacs Code Browser, which is built on CEDET, if I am not mistaken, is one you should look at.

Myself, I've always found that I get by well enough using [etags](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/etags.html) and [ido-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings). You might also want to look at [Speedbar](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/speedbar.shtml) (part of CEDET) as a halfway house between more minimalist solutions and ECB.

Comment: for c & c++ it's better to use gtags - CEDET has built-in support for them

Answer (score 5):

I don't use it myself, but it sounds like [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) is what you are looking for:

> Emacs already is a great environment for writing software, but there are additional areas that need improvement. Many new ideas for integrated environments have been developed in newer products, such as Microsoft's Visual environment, JBuilder, or Eclipse. CEDET is a project which implements several advanced features developers have come to expect from an Editor.

The Emacs wiki also has [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForDevStudioUsers) with some tips for IDE users.

Answer (score 1):

See also: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Support_for_Projects.